# Array value type deduction in a function template

Tags: c++, templates

I have following concern regarding following code snippet:

```
template<std::size_t Dim, std::size_t N,
  typename RangeType1, typename RangeType2>
void multilinear_interp(
  const RangeType1 (&coordsFrom)[Dim],
  const std::array<RangeType2, N>& field)
{
   // do something
}

int main()
{ 
    std::vector<double> x{}, y{};
    std::vector<float> f0{}, f1{};

    multilinear_interp<2, 2>({x, y}, {f0, f1});
}
```

It looks like compiler can deduce RangeType1, but cannot deduce RangeType2 and compilation fails. Is there a possibility to use std::array without explicitly specifying all template parameters of multiliner_interp? If not then what is special about **const T (&)[Dim]** w.r.t std::array that it can be deduced in above context?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the *exact* error you get? Please copy-paste (as text) the full and complete (including possible informational notes) output of the compiler into the question body.

Comment: error: no matching function for call to ‘multilinear_interp<2, 2>(<brace-enclosed initializer list>, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   multilinear_interp<2, 2>({x, y}, {f0, f1});

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, there's no deducing a container like `std::array` from `{f0, f1}` or even `{{f0, f1}}` (if one's initial thought is brace elision). The reason is that a brace enclosed initializer is not an expression. It doesn't have a type to deduce *from*. So it's classified in general as a non-deduced context (i.e. template arguments cannot be deduced from it).

As for why it works in the case of a regular C-style array reference, it's because an exception is made explicitly for them and `std::initializer_list` parameters. All of this is described in the same standard paragraph:

> **[temp.deduct.call]**
>
> [1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.deduct.call#1) Template argument deduction is done by comparing each function
>   template parameter type (call it `P`) that contains *template-parameters*
>   that participate in template argument deduction with the type of the
>   corresponding argument of the call (call it `A`) as described below. If
>   removing references and cv-qualifiers from `P` gives
>   `std​::​initializer_­list<P'>` or `P'[N]` for some `P'` and `N` and the
>   argument is a non-empty initializer list ([dcl.init.list]), then
>   deduction is performed instead for each element of the initializer
>   list, taking `P'` as a function template parameter type and the
>   initializer element as its argument, and in the `P'[N]` case, if `N` is a
>   non-type template parameter, `N` is deduced from the length of the
>   initializer list. Otherwise, an initializer list argument causes the
>   parameter to be considered a non-deduced context ([temp.deduct.type]).